# SOAP Service Reference in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal app

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro, soap-client

I try to add a reference to a SOAP WebService. No problem adding it to the Windows 8.1 part of the project.

But no chance to do the same for the WP 8.1. Somehow I could only add a new "Push Notification" as a reference.

Adding the generated reference.cs to the WP project directly leads to many unresolved references in System.ServiceModel (i.e. System.ServiceModel.Channels not found).

Any idea?
Maybe its not in the current beta?

VS 2013 Update 2 RC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While not a proper solution, a workaround has been posted by Microsoft: [WCF Add Service Reference Not Supported for Windows Phone 8.1 XAML Applications](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/06fc8c48-3d85-4867-82e7-517f1ba68256/wcf-add-service-reference-not-supported-for-windows-phone-81-xaml-applications?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK)

> Windows Phone 8.1 XAML applications does not support the System.ServiceModel namespace, and therefore you are not able to right click references in the project and choose Add Service Reference. The recommended solution is to add a REST endpoint to your WCF endpoint, and access the WCF application through the REST endpoint using HttpClient.