# Call SOAP WS from Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-8, soap, windows-phone-8.1

I have read all post that support for calling WS from Windows Phone 8.1 has been removed and you cannot do more right click, or even import a proxy because some classes are missing.

Also I have read this that suggest changing the endpoint, but that is not an option since I don't own the server where I have to do a call.
[SOAP Service Reference in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894967/soap-service-reference-in-windows-phone-8-1-universal-app)

What other alternatives are there?
Maybe an HTTPClient that parses the XML?
Any other ideas?

Comment: out of interest, what did you end up doing? Thanks!

Comment: I implemented HTTPClient and generated and parsed all the XML.   Its not ideal but it works.